# My MacBook detects an non-existent headphone output

Tags: audio, headphones

I have a M1 Macbook air.[image: my mac's specifications]

Everything worked fine until my cat stepped in the keyboard- now, every time I open my Mac after it's been slept for some hours, it's muted and I have to go to settings, sound, output and change MANUALLY to the Mac's speakers every time and it's annoying. Then the sound works normally.

I don't know why is it detecting some headphones when I certainly never connected more than the charger. I don't know how to make these settings predetermined again. I really don't know what to do. [image]

Comment: what kind of cat is it :)

Comment: Try blowing your headphone jack with canned air (dont do this via mouth, your mouth has conductive saliva) or cleaning it out with a small brush or q-tip. If two of the contacts are shorted (i believe), it will think a headphone is plugged in). Maybe your cat left something conductive in there.

Comment: I like the idea of blowing out the port but then thought this could drive something conductive into some other place that could cause problems.  I’d try vacuuming first.  Take care though as the moving dry air can build up a charge and zap something.  Canned air has something in it to keep things from getting zapped.

Comment: Solved! Thank you, all I had to do was to connect a pair of headphones in the headphone jack, and then disconnect. It disappeared. You two saved my lifeee.